# Laravel7, user's phone (unique) by update throw 'The phone has already been taken.'

Tags: laravel, validation, updates

In profile.blade, while updating the inputs in the profile getting Error The phone has already been taken.

**Controller:**

```php
public function profileUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $messages = [
        'user_name.required'  => __('The User name field is required.'),
        'last_name.required'  => __('The Last Name field is required.'),
        'first_name.required' => __('The First Name field is required.'),
        'phone.required'      => __('The Phone field is required.'),
    ];
    $request->validate([
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name'  => 'required|max:255',
        'email'      => [
            'required',
            'email',
            'max:255',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
        ],
        'user_name' => [
            'required',
            'max:255',
            'min:4',
            'string',
            'alpha_dash',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
        ],
        'phone' => [
            'required',
            'unique:users',
            'min:10',
            'numeric',
            Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
        ],
    ], $messages);

    $input = $request->except('bio');

    $user->fill($input);
    $user->bio = clean($request->input('bio'));
    $user->birthday = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($user->birthday));
    $user->user_name = Str::slug($request->input('user_name'), "_");
    $user->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with('success', __('Update successfully'));
}
```

**In the View blade:**

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ __("Phone Number") }}</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{ old('phone',$dataUser->phone) }}" name="phone" placeholder="{{ __('Phone Number') }}" class="form-control">
    <i class="fa fa-phone input-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ __("Birthday") }}</label>
    <input type="text" value="{{ old('birthday',$dataUser->birthday ? display_date($dataUser->birthday) : '') }}" name="birthday" placeholder="{{ __('Birthday') }}" class="form-control date-picker">
    <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake input-icon"></i>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{ __("About Yourself") }}</label>
    <textarea name="bio" rows="5" class="form-control">{{ old('bio', $dataUser->bio) }}</textarea>
</div>
```

If the Phone is already saved and no change is done with it, the error (The phone has already been taken) is thrown.

need help to resolve the problem,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repeating the unique rule in phone.

```
'phone' => [
    'required',
    'unique:users', // Remove this line.
    'min:10',
    'numeric',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)
],
```

`unique:users` is the same as `Rule::unique('users')`. Since `unique:users` does not ignore `$user->id`, it throws the validation error.